# What does the app property of the appConfig variable in a Yeoman generator-angular generated Gruntfile.js mean?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to figure out what `require('./bower.json').appPath || 'src',` of the `app` property of the `appConfig` means. I understand its a path but not sure what these two paths are being used for. I can only guess that these are the paths for the files of my app.

My `Gruntfile.js` was `// Generated on 2014-08-26 using generator-angular 0.9.5`

Here is the full `appConfig` code:

```
  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'src',
    dist: 'dist'
  };
```

I should also mention that I changed `app` to `src`. That is the only change.

Comment: _I can only guess that these are the paths for the files of my app._ that's exactly what it is. It tries to require an object found in bower.json and use the appPath property, and falls back to the string if it fails

Comment: ahh ok. thanks. I never knew aobut the `appPath` property.